# Access/SQL make/update table query with sum function

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

Total noob here, so bear with me. I'll try to explain this two ways.

When I add a totals row, i can use Group By and Sum to get what i need, except that i need the output to include other columns that i don't want summed or grouped by.

[Amount] [check number] [region]

If the check number matches, i want to sum the amount, even if the region is different, but i also want the output to include the region.

It seems like it should be pretty common, but so far, all i can figure out how to sum if region matches, or to not output the region.

(I'm sure i sound like a total idiot. Let me know if there's anything i can make more clear.)

Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Can we see your functions? Generally, the columns that you select need to be an aggregate (like Sum) or included in the Group By.

Comment: Can you provide us with some code ?

Comment: What i have so far is this `code SELECT Imported.ï»¿AccountId, Imported.GiftDate, Imported.CheckNumber, Sum(Imported.TransactionAmount) AS SumOfTransactionAmount
FROM Imported
GROUP BY Imported.ï»¿AccountId, Imported.GiftDate, Imported.CheckNumber;
`

Comment: The problem is, there are a lot more (text) columns i would like on the output, but i don't want them to be grouped by.

Comment: The reason the other columns need to be included as part of the Group By is because if they are not grouped, they could be unique. You need to decide, from the records returned by the Group By, which full records to display. You'll need to have aggregates for the other columns as well if you do that, like MAX/MIN/SUM etc.

Comment: Very unclear to me. Could you add to your question a data sample of your table(s) and the results you want to achieve ?